# Why are the data types double value got incorrect result in java

Tags: java

> I have a sample program which i got a wrong result value in java
>   **please check below**

```
package javaapplication3;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApplication3 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        double result=0;
        int a=0, b=0;
        System.out.println("ENTER FIRST NUMBER ");
         a=s.nextInt(); 
         System.out.println("ENTER SECOND NUMBER ");
         b=s.nextInt();
         if(b==0){
           System.out.println("DIVISION NOT POSSIBLE");
         }
         result =a/b;
         System.out.println("RESULT = " + result);
 }
}
```

when i input 4 and 5 i got a wrong result returns to 0.0 it must be 0.8 Do you have any idea what's going on? I am a beginner in java programming please help.

Comment: Of course. You're dividing integer values.

Comment: You the man you save my day thanks .

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
result =(double)a / (double)b;
```

If you want `double` result, then use `double` in division.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your answer, but it would work equally well to cast just `a` or just `b` to double.  If the type of either arg to the `/` operator is double, then Java will implicitly cast the other arg to double.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on what sʜʀɪɴɪᴠᴀs sʜᴜᴋʟᴀ said:

The statement `result = a/b;` is evaluated in two steps:  First the `/` operator is evaluated, and *then* the `=` is performed.

Since both args to the `/` operator are ints, the operator is evaluated using integer division, and the result is zero.

Then, the `=` is performed.  Since the right-hand-side is an int, and the left-hand-side is double, the int value is implicitly cast to double.

sʜʀɪɴɪᴠᴀs sʜᴜᴋʟᴀ's solution was to explicitly cast both of the `/` args to double so that double division will be performed instead, and the result will be 0.8 as you expected.  Actually, you only have to cast one of the two operands, and the other will be implicitly *promoted* to the same type.

---

Note:  The answer is not *really* 0.8, it is only very close.  There is no `double` value that is exactly equal to 0.8.  If you see "0.8" in the output, it is because the print routine rounded the result to some small number of significant figures.